# Creating a cookie to control Jquery toggled content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I would like to add a cookie that controls whether my collapsible content is shown or hidden. The default when the site loads is shown. I have tried and failed to implement cookies thus far so the raw code is shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".toggle_parent").toggle(function(){
      $(".toggled_content").slideUp();
      $("img.upmid").attr('src',"images/downmid.png");
    },function(){
      $(".toggled_content").slideDown();
      $("img.upmid").attr('src',"images/upmid.png");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this by setting a cookie value each time the state changes and examining that cookie value when the page loads to set the initial state to match the previously set cookie value:

Add this CSS to make the default state by closed so if the desired end-state is closed,it won't initially show as open and then close:

```
.toggled_content {display: none;}
```

Add this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){

      function hideContent() {
          $(".toggled_content").slideUp();
          $("img.upmid").attr('src',"images/downmid.png");
      }

      function showContent() {
          $(".toggled_content").slideDown();
          $("img.upmid").attr('src',"images/upmid.png");
      }

      // set initial state based on cookie value
      // assumes default state is closed
      if (readCookie("updown") == "down") {
          showContent();
      }

      $(".toggle_parent").toggle(function(){
          hideContent();
          createCookie("updown", "up", 30)
      },function(){
          showContent();
          createCookie("updown", "down", 30);
    });
  });


function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked straight away. Just for aesthetics would there be a better way to keep the div closed on load. At present if toggled closed, its loads open and then slides back up?

Comment: @user1558300 - I've modified my answer so that the initial state is closed so if the desired final state is closed, it will just stay closed.  If the desired final state is open, it will open as the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the shop, buy a pack of random cookies. When you come to eat each one, collapse the content if the cookie contains chocolate, else expand it. :P

On a more serious note, I recommend [the jQuery cookies plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) - this allows you to set, get or delete cookies. Put an ID on the parent, and on collapsing the content set a cookie containing the ID in the name. Unset on expand. On page load check the cookie; if it exists, do the slideUp call etc.

You may also like to check out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) - there are some useful features for showing and hiding content there, such as the accordion.

Comment: Also note that, depending on browser support, you may wish to look into localstorage - this can be useful to lower the overhead if you don't need the cookie on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a jQuery plugin, you could use [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). It is very simple to use.

Setting a cookie:

```
$.cookie("cookie name", "value");
```

Get a cookies value:

```
alert($.cookie("cookie name"));
```